# Call some irregular named files in a directory using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a directory having more than 100 files with irregular prefix names e.g.

```
 ABC2001.txt
 abc2002.txt 
 Abc2003.txt 
 aBc2004.txt 
SABC2001.txt 
sabc2002.txt 
SAbc2003.txt 
saBc2004.txt
```

I want to call only those files which are started with combination of a/A, b/B, c/C with its year and work with them. I could do this manually for 3 x 3 combinations using the script as

```
y1=2001; y2=2004
while [ y1 -le y2 ]
do
F1=ABC; F2=ABc; F3=Abc; F4=abc; F5=aBC; F6=abC; F7=abc; F8=AbC; F9=aBc
if [ -f $F1$y1.txt ] || [ -f $F2$y1.txt ] || [ -f $F3$y1.txt ] || [ -f $F4$y1.txt ] || [ -f $F5$y1.txt ] || [ -f $F6$y1.txt ] ||; then f1=ifile.txt
fi
doing some calculation with $f1
(( y1++ ))
done
```

My problem is for large number files of such pattern. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in [aA][bB][cC][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt; do
  echo $file
done
```

Note that it there are no matching files, this will print the literal string `[aA][bB][cC][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt`.  In bash, you can suppress that behavior by setting failglob: `shopt -s failglob`